# RxJS subscribe to change in subscribers count

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables, subject-observer

**Problem:**
I'm using Subject observable to pass String data between components (that are too far apart in the hierarchy). I would like to be able to tell how many subscribers there are to the Subject when a component subscribes or unsubscribes. How can above be achieved? Sorry I'm new to RxJS.

**Backstory:**
I have a simple search/filter field at the top (navbar). The main view displays a component, some components are searchable, other are not. Each searchable component subscribes to the search/filter (via service). **I would like to hide search/filter field when there are no subscribers and display when there is at least one subscriber.**

I know the above logic can be archived via routes, but I would like to do it via observable count.

Comment: Yes, Subject is already in the service

Answer (score 0):

The [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) class from Rxjs exposes an array of observers that you can query to get the number of observers.

```
let obs: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("Something");
console.log(obs);
obs.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("Subscriber 1");
});
obs.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("Subscriber 2");
});
console.log(obs.observers.length);
obs.next("Something else");
```

Stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-observerscount1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)